# Why "no projects found to import"?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, project

I am trying to "import existing project into workspace". As the "root directory" I select the directory where all my .java (and .class) files are located. Eclipse writes me that "no projects are found to import". Why?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Eclipse is looking for eclipse projects, meaning its is searching for eclipse-specific files in the root directory, namely `.project` and `.classpath`. You either gave Eclipse the wrong directory (if you are importing a eclipse project) or you actually want to create a new project from existing source(`new`->`java project`->`create project from existing source`).

I think you probably want the second one, because Eclipse projects usually have separate source & build directories. If your sources and .class files are in the same directory, you probably didn't have a eclipse project.

Comment: I think you are right. I have removed ".project" and ".classpath" files from the directory and then I got the described problem. But I just tried to "create project from existing source". It seems to work. But I still do not have the ".project" and ".classpath" files into the directory. So, eclipse created a project but it did not create files associated with the project. Do you know why?

Comment: Check your workspace folder. I believe there should be a folder with the name of your project and the two files in it. One of them probably has the path to where your real classes are.

Comment: there is no such thing as create project from existing source....I cannot see it.......when you press new -> java project .........then there are no more options, you just get the dialog for adding a new project.

Comment: Correction: this "create project from existing source" option doesn't exit in new eclipse versions. See my answer below in case you have the new eclipse.

Answer (score 193):

This answer is same as Laura's answer , however, in new eclipse versions you will not be able to see a "create project from existing source" option.

Hence you can do this instead:

- Goto **File** > **New** > **Project**
- Select the type of project, click **Next**
- Uncheck *Use default location*
- Click on **Browse** to navigate to your source folder, or type in the path to your source
- Click **Finish**

Taken from this [discussion forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/544575/) in eclipse.org

Comment: +1. I spend my 20 minutes in finding 'create project from existing source' option.

Comment: In a newer version of Android... From the menu just select:
File->New->Project (not Android Project nor Java Project).
Then under Wizards select: 
Android->Android Project from Existing Code

Comment: If you don't have Android Project as an option like @paiego suggested, you can also use New JavaScript Project.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It shows '<projectname> overlaps the location of another project : <projectname>'. Using Eclipse luna (4.4.0).

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733089/eclipse-error-overlaps-the-location-of-another-project-when-trying-to-cr

Comment: It does not work for me (eclipse 2020-6) because if i uncheck "Use default location" the Finish button also gets greyed out so it cant be created.

Answer (score 24):

One solution to this is to use Maven. From the project root folder do mvn eclipse:clean followed by mvn eclipse:eclipse. This will generate the .project and .classpath files required by eclipse.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed to hear...  "click"

Comment: this is what I am looking for. Really helped me. Thanks @PaulF!

Answer (score 13):

In new updated eclipse the option "`create project from existing source`" is found here, 
`File>New>Project>Android>Android` Project from Existing Code. Then browse to root directory.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

**I have a perfect solution for this problem. After doing following simple steps you will be able to Import your source codes in Eclipse!**

First of all, the **reason** why you can not Import your project into Eclipse workstation is that you do not have *.project* and *.classpath* file.

Now we know why this happens, so all we need to do is to create *.project* and *.classpath* file inside the project file. Here is how you do it:

**First create *.classpath* file:**

1. create a new txt file and name it as .classpath
2. copy paste following codes and save it:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <classpath>
   <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
   <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
   <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
   </classpath>`

**Then create  *.project* file:**

1. create a new txt file and name it as .project
2. copy paste following codes:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <projectDescription>
   <name>HereIsTheProjectName</name>
   <comment></comment>
   <projects>
   </projects>
   <buildSpec>
   <buildCommand>
   <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
   <arguments>
   </arguments>
   </buildCommand>
   </buildSpec>
   <natures>
   <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
   </natures>
   </projectDescription>`
3. you have to change the name field to your project name. you can do this in line 3 by changing *HereIsTheProjectName* to your own project name. then save it.

That is all, Enjoy!!

Comment: I found copying the files from another project files, and just changing the name.

Comment: Exactly. If the project which you wants to import doesn't have .project and .classpath files then eclipse/sts will not identify your project to import

Answer (score 4):

**Reason** :
  your ID is not able to find the .project file. This happens in git commit where many time people don't push .project file

**Solution** :
If you have maven install then use following stapes

1. mvn eclipse:clean
2. mvn eclipse:eclipse

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

After a long time finally i found that!
Here my Way:
File -> New Project -> Android Project From Existing Code -> 
Browse to your project root directory
finish!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have I just have `.project` and `.classpath` files in the directory, the only way that works (for me at least) with the latest version of Eclipse is:

1. Create a new Android project

   - `File` -> `New` -> `Project...` -> `Android` -> `Android Application Project` -> `Next >`
   - Fill in the values on this page and the following according to your application's needs
2. Get your existing code into the project you just created

   - Right click the `src` file in the Package Explorer
   - `General` -> `File System` -> `Next >`
   - `Browse` to your project, select the necessary files, hit `Finish`

After this, you should have a project with all your existing code as well as new `.project` and `.classpath` files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I've modified .project xml-file. When I reverted files to original version the project was created, then I was able to import project. Maybe it helps someone who has the same kind of problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you are building a maven project through a command console, make sure the following is at the end of the command:

```
eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this problem for android projects. follow the below mentioned steps
new->android project->create project from existing source and in this you can give your code location. Now, it will import all the specified project code and will work fine