# No projects are found to import warning message is displaying in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Whenever I try to import an existing project to Eclipse, I get a warning message-  No projects are found to import.

[image: screenshot is here]

Answer (score 0):

Well, Eclipse always look into the .project file to see if the project is compliant to the type of project you choose when you select the import. If the project is not Eclipse Project or is not the type of project you choose, You will definately get that error message. Look into the eclipse documentation for more information. You can also look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638016/why-no-projects-found-to-import) thread.